# Why does changing style via JavaScript gets affected by CSS transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am simply changing changing the `color` and `background-color` of a button when I click on it.

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="myButton" onclick="ChangeColor()"/>
```

The **CSS** of this button contains CSS transition for the `color` and `background-color`, however, on the `:hover` pseudo-element I didn't add any styles, I didn't change the color.

```css
#myButton{
     color:#3399FF;
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     /* These transitions are supposed to change the color in case I hover over the button */
     -webkit-transition: background 0.5s,color 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s,color 0.5s;
            transition: background 0.5s,color 0.5s;
}
#myButton:hover{
     /* But since there's nothing here, the color won't change when I hover */
}
```

Now, when I change the styles via JavaScript, they change while using the transitions, means, the colors will change after `0.5s`, and not instantly.

```
function ChangeColor()
{
   document.getElementById("myButton").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
   document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundColor = "#3399FF";
}
```

This is a really good thing, and I like it, but I'm just wondering, how does JavaScript respect CSS3 transitions? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: `CSS3` transitions are supported natively by the browser I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transitions are applied whenever the value of the property is changed. It doesn't matter whether you change it on hover, focus, resize (with a media query for example), click or any other event via JavaScript.

In general, you have a transition between two states of the element. You first define the initial state:

```css
#myButton {
     color: #39f;
     background: #fff;
     transition: .5s;
}
```

When you change the value of either of those two properties (and it doesn't matter whether you do this using the `:hover` pseudo-class or JavaScript), your element will go into another state and you are going to have a transition between the values of the properties from the initial state and those from this new state.

Answer (score 2):

The method you're using to change the style with JavaScript is essentially a way of manually changing the `style` attribute directly on the element itself. Any time the style changes to something else and you have a transition defined for it, that transition will activate to change to the new style. That includes changes that JavaScript makes to the styles.